# Working of a clamper circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, resistors, diodes, clamp

I was reading about the clamper circuit on wikipedia and found this below image for a positive clamper circuit.

[image]

My question is

During the positive (Rising/increasing portion) half of the input AC waveform, the capacitor gets charged right? Meaning the positive charges are accumulated on the left side of the capacitor plate and negative charges are on the right side of the capacitor plate.

So, in that case, during this instant, the output voltage is taken across the resistor.
So, the resistor at that time, is connected to the right side of the capacitor which is having negative charges.
So, my doubt is - "When the input AC signal increases, the output voltage cannot also increase in the same fashion because the output voltage is taken across the resistor and it is connected to the right side of the capacitor plate which at time has negative charges, right?"

Can someone clarify what I am misunderstanding over here?

Comment: Look at Vout and Vin. Compare them as instantaneous values. Then you'll see that a net positive charge occurs on the right hand plate compared to the left hand side (after the fullness of time).

Comment: Yes, but the net positive charge will get accumulated on after the first cycle right, Andy? My doubt is, how does the output follow the input during the very first increasing portion of the half cycle ?

Comment: If R is very big, during the first half cycle, the capacitor acts like a short and lets through the signal almost with zero reduction. As soon as the first half cycle is over, the negative portion of the input waveform will force current into the diode clamp and hence, that right hand plate remains locked to close to 0 volts. So, there's an example of the right hand side being charged more positively than the left hand side.

Comment: Oh, I am thinking like, during the first half cycle, the voltage across the capacitor cannot change instantly and the charge accumulation also does not seem to add up

Comment: Just to give a little more background, my previous question of RC time constant being greater than the time period of the input signal, is in relation to this clamper circuit only.

Comment: Based on the previous answer @Andyaka, you said when time constant of RC is very much greater than the input, the output cannot follow the input right? But in this case, I read that the clamper circuit uses RC >> Time period of AC input. But how come, the output is following the input? Can you please help me with my misunderstanding

Comment: But in a clamper circuit, why should RC time constant >> Time period of the AC input signal

Comment: The previous question I made an answer using a low pass RC filter. Look at this circuit on this question; the circuit is a high-pass RC filter. Things change when it swaps around but, nevertheless, I shall make a simulation and show you in more detail....

Comment: Sure, thank you. I read that RC time constant must be high enough so that the "The magnitude of R and C must be chosen such that the time constant RC is large enough to ensure that the voltage across the capacitor does not discharge significantly during the interval the diode is nonconducting." But  during the charging phase also, the output voltage would not charge instantly to the input voltage right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to remember that this circuit, at its heart, contains a high-pass filter. In your previous question, I answered it from the perspective of a low-pass filter. For this particular circuit (using a high-pass) you actually want the time constant to be very long for a clamper.

So, here's a reminder of what happens to a square wave when it passes through different RC filtering values before moving on to the clamping element: -

[image]

So, here are the three waveforms from top to bottom: -

- RC
- 10 x RC
- 100 x RC

And, you should be able to see that with a square wave used as the source, the best fit for that waveform at the output is when we have 100 x RC. Of course this is the opposite to a low-pass but, hopefully you can begin to see that.

To the clamper (using 100 x RC) with a sinewave feed...

[image]

As per without the diode clamps, the best performer is the 100 x RC circuit at the bottom but, it's got some distortion and maybe, upping  it to 1000 x RC is better so, here's input and output waveforms shown together: -

[image]

Green is output and orange is input. Clearly, the output signal remains above the instantaneous value of the input signal apart from the first half cycle (where they are close to the same value).

> *the positive charges are accumulated on the left side of the capacitor
> plate and negative charges are on the right side of the capacitor
> plate.*

No, it's the other way round.

Schematic used: -

[image]